# rails_admin how to override an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I need to override the [new action](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/new.rb) for just one of my models.

Basically, all I'm trying to do is set some values right before @object.save

I've searched a lot, but rails_admin documentation is not very detailed in that regard and most of the tutorials are about creating a custom action.

Anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[customize actions](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions#use-existing-actions-and-customize-them)

```
# config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
    new do 

    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Where should I put that?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm trying to do this with the rails_admin gem, not the active_admin gem

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you

```
config.actions do
  dashboard
  new do
     ...
  end
  index

end
```

First argument is the key of the action. It will be the `i18n_key, the url_fragment, the action_name, the authorization_key`, etc. You can override each of these individually. See the respective class and the

> [Base](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/base.rb)

Action class to get the list of these options.